# Libgdx, How to set Alpha on a Bitmap Font?

Tags: android, libgdx

Today I would like to change the alpha of a bitmap font in LibGdx

I discovered that the BitmapFont class has a `setColor` method so I pass in the following. Note I do not want to change the colour so I set these these values to the same

```
 myBitmapFont.setColor(myColour.r,
                       myColour.g,
                       myColour.b,
                       MY_ALPHA)
```

And my alpha is

```
 MY_ALPHA= 0.1f
```

However, the alpha is not applying, anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the entire code (from initialising the BitmapFont, to drawing it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised my error. I forgot that I don't draw the `BitmapFont` directly but use the `GlyphLayout` instance to perform the text drawing (because `GlyphLayout` performs text measuring)

```
internal fun BitmapFont.drawFontInCenterOfContainer(batch: Batch, glyphLayout: GlyphLayout, containerWidth: Float, containerHeight: Float, offsetX: Float = 0f, offsetY: Float = 0f) {
    this.draw(
            batch,
            glyphLayout,
            offsetX + containerWidth / 2 - glyphLayout.width / 2,
            offsetY + containerHeight / 2 + glyphLayout.height / 2)
}
```

So even though I called `setColor` on the BitmapFont instance, It did not apply because I must also call `setText` on the `GlyphLayout`

```
 myBitmapFont.setColor(myColour.r,
                   myColour.g,
                   myColour.b,
                   MY_ALPHA)

glyphLayout.setText(myBitmapFont, myText)
```

And looking at the `setText` method of `GlyphLayout`

```
/** Calls {@link #setText(BitmapFont, CharSequence, int, int, Color, float, int, boolean, String) setText} with the whole
     * string, the font's current color, and no alignment or wrapping. */
    public void setText (BitmapFont font, CharSequence str) {
        setText(font, str, 0, str.length(), font.getColor(), 0, Align.left, false, null);
    }
```

It applies the `BitmapFont` colour